# Is it possible to use spring ThreadPoolTaskExecutor for PubSub subscribers?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

The section about concurrency [here](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/pull#java_4) uses `ExecutorProivder`, but since my project is in `spring-boot` I am not sure if it would be fine to use this for managing threads when there already exists [ThreadPoolTaskExecutor](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/concurrent/ThreadPoolTaskExecutor.html). Is it possible to use these threads managed by spring for the subscribers? If not, is it okay to use the `ExecutorProivder` or could it be a problem later on? I know there exists a spring abstraction for google pub-sub, but I do not want to use that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible for you to provide your own executor (e.g., provide your Spring-managed threads). You can do so by overriding the getExecutor() method to return your own scheduled executor service, like [this example](https://github.com/googleapis/java-pubsub/blob/master/google-cloud-pubsub/src/test/java/com/google/cloud/pubsub/v1/SubscriberTest.java#L144).

You could also consider following [the example in the concurrency docs you referenced](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/pull#java_4) to create a separate executor specifically for PubSub subscribing, for more thread isolation.

Either approach could work.